# Loop doesn't find a candidate even though a candidate exists?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've recently started developing a discord bot (using the discord.js library). The bots purpose would be to find small servers in a game called ROBLOX.

I've already learned the ROBLOX api, and written most of the code.
When I type the command, the loop runs through all of the servers, but to my surprise, it doesn't find a suitable candidate.

This is a part of my code:

```
        result = api.responseText
        found = false
        number = parseInt(args[0])

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            if(result[i].playing <= number) {
                message.reply("found candidate")
                found = true
            } else {
                if (i == result.length - 1) {
                    message.reply("no candidate found.")
                }
            }
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/InEYM.png

The image shows roughly what the JSON looks like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh, shoot! Looks like the image didn't load. I'll link the API itself. https://games.roblox.com/v1/games/5208655184/servers/public?limit=100&cursor=

Comment: Is there any chance that playing is a string? Have you tried to parseInt it too?

Comment: No, I haven't, I will however try.

Comment: Also what is the value of number?

Comment: This does not work, though I might've misunderstood you, was this what you meant? 
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                    resultNumber = parseInt(result[i].playing)
                    if(resultNumber <= number) {
                        message.reply("found candidate")
                        found = true
                    } else {
                        if (i == result.length - 1) {
                            message.reply("no candidate found.")
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: Ok, can you give us a result example as a string and not in image?

Comment: The value of number is args[0].         const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
                number = parseInt(args[0])

Comment: Alright, let me upload it to pastebin.

Comment: Also, are you sure you needresponseText and not a json version? Can you edit in a copry of responseText result?

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` show?

Comment: api.responseText is JSON I'm pretty sure.

Comment: It shows the image I've linked in the question, I can however paste it into pastebin and link it here, I will do so.

Comment: https://ghostbin.co/paste/c3xvmds

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error, especially relating to `if(result[i].playing <= number)`? JSON is a string as far as javascript is concerned and `.responseText` usually contains a string. Trying to treat it like an object should be throwing at least a warning.

Comment: It does not show me any kind of error or warning.

Comment: Would it be easier if I posted all of my code?

Comment: Assuming `.responseText` really is a javascript object and not just a string, the code you show seems like it should be working. Without more details, especially around how you loaded the `api` and `args` variables, we won't be able to help. I would suggest trying things like `console.log('playing', result[i].playing)` and `console.log(typeof result)` to see that the data is actually what you think it is.

Comment: You are correct, the type of 'result' is string. I will post my code, I will remove the client.login() part with my token so that no one can steal it. https://ghostbin.co/paste/st3t

Comment: Then you probably wanted `result = JSON.parse(api.responseText);` instead.

Comment: But when I do that, it just freezes up on "Searching with the filter: " (filter). Any ideas what might've went wrong here?

Comment: You'll probably also need to reference the entries as `result.data[i].playing`, based on the structure of the data you uploaded earlier.

Comment: Tried that, the same issue is happening, I could invite you to my discord server, that would allow easier communication.

Comment: Sure, I can do that.

Comment: https://discord.gg/knNBwY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues:

- `.responseText` is likely a JSON-encoded string, not an object. This will need to be parsed into an object.
- `result.data` is the array containing the server data (specific to the Roblox Web API), not `result`. There are three places where this will need to be updated.

These can be fixed like this:

```
    result = JSON.parse(api.responseText)
    found = false
    number = parseInt(args[0])

    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++){
        if(result.data[i].playing <= number) {
            message.reply("found candidate")
            found = true
        } else {
            if (i == result.data.length - 1) {
                message.reply("no candidate found.")
            }
        }
    }
```

There could also stand to be some error checking as the API may return something else, for example, an error message. Also, the result sets are provided in a paged format so that might need to be handled as well. (Though it looks like the API is currently returning the full set of servers in one call.) I'll leave those for another question if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Try use

```
const filter = result.filter( (item) => item.playing <= number)
const found  = filter.lenght > 0
```